# Does it matter where I SELECT fewer columns in SSIS in order to increase performance?

Tags: sql, performance, select, ssis

Say in a data flow task, I have an OLE DB source. I would like to increase the performance of the SSIS. Does it matter where I SELECT less columns?

1. Create a view in database that SELECT less columns, use that as the source.
2. Type SQL SELECT inside the source to select less columns.
3. Choose the table then untick the columns inside the source.

Thank you

Comment: Start the profiler and capture all three queries. You might be surprised by the results - it can happen that all of them pull identical number of columns. Next to the exact query executed, you will see the number of CPU cycles and Reads which would tell you the differences, if any. After that you can post the results here for all of us to benefit and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SSIS ,you shouldn't be using `Table name or view from a variable`  as they tend to pull all the data .It behaves as [Select *](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1840/sql-server-integration-services-ssis-best-practices/).

```
The adapter opens a rowset-based on the table or view. Then it calls OpenRowset
in the validation phase to retrieve column metadata, and later in the execution
phase to read out the data.
```

The best way is type out the SQL command which increases the performance . But using View ,
the performance is increased many folds .Check [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlperf/archive/2007/04/29/set-up-ole-db-source-to-read-from-view-efficiently.aspx) article for using View in OLEDB SOurce

Comment: So the best is to create views in database first, then *don't use table or view as source*, rather, type out the SQL to select from the views?

Comment: The article does explains some performance gains using view and typing the sql in oledb source but the only way to prove that is  using the all the 2 methods (SQLcommand and view) along with the sql profiler to see the performance gain and lastly as @billinkc suggested u just can't have faster throughput more than what your source (SQL Server or other RDBMS) can provide .

Answer (score 4):

A trivial clarification on @praveen's answer. There is a performance difference, however slight, between selecting a table in the drop down list and writing the equivalent SELECT * (and even then, enumerate your columns) because of the overhead of the open rowset call.

That said, if you need to get the best performance out of SSIS, be as explicit as possible. If you only need 5 columns out of 30, explicitly select those columns. SSIS might pull back all 30 columns and filter them client-side. You just wasted network bandwidth *and* you had to read the clustered index to get all that data where a covering index might have existed. Increased read cost + increased network cost + increased memory cost for the columns SSIS is going to discard? You're paying a good bit of expense up front before any work can begin.

You cannot get faster throughput than your starting component supplies.

Comment: Just to let you know @billinkc, I'm going to steal that last line for training my staff!

Comment: So the best is to create views in database first, then don't use table or view as source, rather, type out the SQL to select from the views?